# How to launch Windows 10 Java JRE

Tags: java, windows, launch

The Java JDK and JRE has been installed and the environment variables set but no Java JRE icon appears on the desktop. How do you start it?

tried running it from the MSDOS command line but ">Java" gets you the jar file interpreter.
I need the java runtime interactive source debugger.

Comment: Uh, in the JDK there is one debugger that might be of interest: [`jhsdb`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jhsdb.html). Is that what you mean? Debugging and such is usually linked to development, so the JDK is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

> The Java JDK and JRE has been installed

You need only one or the other.

- To develop Java apps, install a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit).
- To run an existing Java app, install a [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment).

> no Java JRE icon appears on the desktop

**Java has no built-in [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)** to display on a desktop [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) such as Windows, macOS, or Linux. So no apps icons will appear.

In the `bin` directory of a JDK/JRE, you will find [several console apps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/index.html). For example, the `java` console app is used to run Java apps. Invoke these console apps on a command-line in a terminal app such as [*Windows Terminal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) on the Windows OS.

For example, to see the current version of the default Java installation, on a command-line execute:

```bash
java --version
```

For more info, study a tutorial such as: [Run a Java Application from the Command Line](https://www.baeldung.com/java-run-jar-with-arguments) by Baeldung.

As [commented by Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76223252/how-to-launch-windows-10-java-jre/76223267#comment134418017_76223252), if you want to launch a postmortem debugger to analyze the content of a core dump from a crashed Java Virtual Machine (JVM), use the [`jhsdb`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jhsdb.html) console app.

Another debugging tool is `jdb`. That command demonstrates the [Java Platform Debugger Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Debugger_Architecture) and provides inspection and debugging of a local or remote JVM.

While developing Java software, most folks rely on the debugging facility of their favorite [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html#general-procedure), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html), or [Eclipse](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-debugging).